# Twitter Streaming Connection Perfectly Working on Dev Server but not on Production

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, streaming

I'm part of a team that is developing an app that pulls tweets via Streaming API. So far, everything's been running fine on our dev servers but when we pushed to production, attempting to make a connection to Twitter's stream result in the following:

```
<title>Error 401 UNAUTHORIZED</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /1/statuses/filter.json. Reason:
<pre>    UNAUTHORIZED</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

We've been using the same app for a long time in the dev server and pulling via streaming worked perfectly back then, but when we tried using that app in our production it suddenly won't work. Now, we've created separate apps for the dev and production but same error for production server. I'm also implementing the exponential backoff rule for streaming. Server time are the same. (BTW, I am using tweepy as my twitter library with some customizations)

For authentication to stream, I'm using the accesstoken and accesstokensecret values for account that created the app. What could be causing this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the time on the server. In my experience working with the twitter API, typically the 401 error arises when the connecting system doesn't have a close enough clock to twitter's to complete the authentication process. See:

[Twitter Discussion on this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1403)

[Twitter Developer Issues](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7161)

Pay particular attention to the comments posted in response to the posts at those links.